# Как подставить в два условия where mysql две переменные php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Всем добрый день, как правильно подставить две переменные в условие запроса mysql ? Видимо проблема с ковычками. 
Конфиг сервера :

> libmysql - 5.5.59;
>   MySql - 5.5.59-0+deb8u1-(debian)

Код

```
$userdb = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $username);
$userpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);    
$query =  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login='".$userdb."'" + " AND user_password = '".$userpassword."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
      echo "failed_password";
      exit();
   }
```

Comment: Попробуйте так `$query =  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login='".$userdb."'  AND user_password = '".$userpassword."' ");`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $query =  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login='".$userdb."'" + " AND user_password = '".$userpassword."'");
```

замени на

```
$query =  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login='".$userdb."' AND user_password = '".$userpassword."'");
```

Comment: А еще лучше так: $query =  mysqli_query(
   $link,
   sprintf("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_login='%s' AND user_password = '%s'", $userdb, $userpassword)
  );

Comment: Эта методика кроме более читабельного вида имеет за собой какие либо плюсы? производительность может быть?

Comment: Конкретно в данном примере - да. Однако, стоит помнить, что sprintf имеет все возможности форматирования исходного printf, что означает, что вы можете сделать гораздо больше, чем просто вставлять значения переменных в строки. Например, укажите формат номера (шестнадцатеричный, десятичный, восьмеричный), количество десятичных знаков, отступы и многое другое.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать